# Pandas Fill Column with Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
   A    B    C    D    
0  1    0   nan  nan  
1  8    0   nan  nan  
2  8    1   nan  nan  
3  2    1   nan  nan  
4  0    0   nan  nan  
5  1    1   nan  nan
```

and i have a dictionary like this:

```
dc = {'C': 5, 'D' : 10}
```

I want to fill the `nan`values in the data frame with the dictionary but only for the cells in which the column B values are 0, i want to obtain this:

```
   A    B    C    D    
0  1    0    5    10
1  8    0    5    10
2  8    1   nan  nan  
3  2    1   nan  nan  
4  0    0    5    10
5  1    1   nan  nan
```

I know how to subset the dataframe but i can't find a way to fill the values with the dictionary; any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`fillna`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj27de76-7KAhVDIpoKHXDXBK0QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.fillna.html&usg=AFQjCNHbdi5xNDvPutmhleTYH7dT-8ml7Q&bvm=bv.113943164,d.bGs) with `loc` and pass your dict to it:

```
In [13]: df.loc[df.B==0,:].fillna(dc)
Out[13]:
   A  B  C   D
0  1  0  5  10
1  8  0  5  10
4  0  0  5  10
```

To do it for you dataframe you need to slice with the same mask and assign the result above to it:

```
df.loc[df.B==0, :] = df.loc[df.B==0,:].fillna(dc)

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   A  B   C   D
0  1  0   5  10
1  8  0   5  10
2  8  1 NaN NaN
3  2  1 NaN NaN
4  0  0   5  10
5  1  1 NaN NaN
```